# Calling Objective-C class from basic C, xcode project

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I am try to implement an cocoa  application For USB Detection. Whenever user connects the USB  it automatically detected, this entire part is one C program (Normal C) is orking Fine.

My need is if the system detects a particular USB device, I want to call another application (i.e. another cocoa application) using system function. I open that application, but my problem is if the user removes that USB device (this is also detected in C program), I want to close the second application automatically.

Or, if I add a cocoa user interface/objective-c class in the first application, is it possible to call that class from inside the C program?

Answer (score 1):

One class you could use for this is `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`. Your C program would need to post notifications and your other program(s) would subscribe to them. The scenario would go like this:

- Second App: on launch register to receive "USB Device Removed" messages
- C Program: dectect removed USB device
- C Program: post notification "USB Device Removed"
- Second App: receives notification "USB Device Removed"
- Second App: quits itself

Of course your C program would now become an objective-c program. There is also C alternative, which is `CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter`.

Answer (score 1):

If the object already exists and you can pass a pointer to it, you can use the Objective-C runtime function `objc_msgSend`. For example:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <objc/message.h>

void sendDoneToApp(id app)
{
    /* [app done]; */

    /* get selector for "done" */
    SEL doneSel = sel_registerName("done");

    /* cast objc_msgSend to the type we need */
    void (*sendNoArgsNoRet)(id obj, SEL selector) = (void (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend;

    /* send the message */
    sendNoArgsNoRet(app, doneSel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You could for example look at how libdispatch/[Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) manages this.

The basic idea is to pass C function-pointers + void-pointers to your C library. And then in the passed function you can call Obj-C functions. Example:

```
struct test_s {
    NSString *my_string;
};

void my_function(void *data) {
    struct test_s *context = data;
    NSLog(@"%@", [@"Hello " stringByAppendingString:context->my_string];
}

void main(void) {
    struct test_s context = { @"World!" };

    /* dispatch_sync_f is a C function unaware of Obj-C */
    dispatch_sync_f(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                    &context,
                    my_function);
}
```